# Interpreting DXA results myself

Tags: body-fat, biological-parameter, medical-device

I want to determine my body fat percentage.

Every hospital here in Bangkok offers me the InBody method, which is based on Bio Electrical Impedance and highly sensitive to my hydration levels in the measurements. According to some, measuring my circumference will give me a reading that is of comparable accuracy and significantly cheaper.

Bod Pods or other systems using Air Displacement Plethysmography are nowhere to be found in Bangkok.

I'd much rather use Dual-energy X-ray Absorptiometry (DXA, previously DEXA), a technology used for bone density readings but [increasingly](http://www.nytimes.com/health/guides/test/bone-mineral-density-test/overview.html) used for body composition readings. Hospitals here do have these machines, but seem unaware of this alternative use for them.

So I'm wondering ... what kind of data does such a machine produce? Are they standard readouts that even a non-expert could interpret, would a physician used to InBody readings be able to interpret the results, or would it need to be someone who is used to using the DXA machines for body composition readings?

Answer (score 1):

I definitely agree with you, to not bother with bioelectrical impedance devices as they really are not worth that much.
The dexa scan readouts I have seen in America are pretty straight forward.
They tell you bone density, lean body mass and fat mass and a few other things in a very readable format.
It will give you the data per section of your body such as your left arm is x percent fat mass etc..

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've found ONE hospital in Bangkok who (while initially pushing BEI) are willing to do a DXA scan for this purpose. But they're charging $200 for a reading. That's a bit excessive. Tape measure it is!